# How do I update certain values in different columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called settings in mysql database, it looks like this:

[image: Settings table]

How do I update these values without having a query for each setting?

Code:

```
<?php

function getSetting($name) {
     global $mysqli;

     $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name='{$name}'");

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row['value'];
     }
}

?>

<form name ="settings" method ="post" action="" id="form">

<h2>Settings</h2><br>    

Site Title: <input name="sitetitle" value="<?php getSetting('sitetitle'); ?>" type="text" class="forminput" /><br><br>
Date Format: <input name="dateformat" value="<?php getSetting('dateformat'); ?>" type="text" class="forminput" /><br><br>
Time Format: <input name="timeformat" value="<?php getSetting('timeformat'); ?>" type="text" class="forminput" /><br>

<br>

<input type="submit" name ='submit' value="Save Changes">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure which takes the 3 values as arguments and runs the updates internally. Then your submit can simply call the procedure (1 query)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, would you show me a example of this?

Comment: @Madsen Here's a little blog post that might help: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/-create-and-call-mysql-stored-procedure-database-sql-example-tutorial.html